# Migration of Notes document only to office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, lotus-notes

We have a requirement to migrate Lotus notes document to sharepoint online, Total size of data to be migrated is 24 GB , and there is only one form which has been used in different view of Lotus notes.
I want to estimate the migration process.
What could be the best approach

And what if I want to create my own tool which will run remotely and can connect to Lotus notes database and migrate documents with attachments to sharepoint list??
What are the Api available ??

Answer (score 1):

Their is no OOTB way to migrate the Louts notes to Office 365. You have to pick one of the migration tool available right now in the market. To pick the best for you, Please try them before(i beleive everyone) final selection.

here are few tools:

[Migrate from Lotus Notes and Domino to Microsoft Office 365](http://www.binarytree.com/solutions/office-365-migrations.aspx)

Dell [Migrating Lotus Notes Applications to Microsoft Office 365 and SharePoint Online](https://software.dell.com/whitepaper/migrating-lotus-notes-applications-to-microsoft-office-365-and-sharep821815/)

ALso read this article:

[Third-party mail migration to Office 365 -- fixes and tips](http://community.office365.com/en-us/w/exchange/1043.aspx)

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/613/t/193658.aspx